# SQL query display min count rows only

Tags: sql, oracle11g, count, min

I am trying to only display the cost value of cars which belong to categories with the minimum category count totals

This the query I am trying to use:

```
select model, VIN,cost
from stock
```

Desired Output:

```
Model -     VIN       - Cost
STI     XXXXXXXXXXXX    $55,000
```

I understand that a having operator may be used to count the minimum category totals for each type of car:

```
having count(distinct category)=(select min(count(category)) 
from stock group by category)
```

But i am not not sure on how to implement such an operator

Comment: Nested queries. = select min(cnt) from (select count(...

Comment: give me some test data and i'll try to create a sqlfiddle and do some testing

Comment: show us the table stucture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this query is a bit trickier than it seems.  Use a subquery to get the counts per category, using a window function to get the minimum count.  Then join this back to the original data:

```
select s.model, s.VIN, s.cost
from stock s join
     (select category, count(*) as cnt, min(count(*)) over () as mincnt
      from stock s
      group by category
     ) c
     on s.category = c.category and cnt = mincnt
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use a window function inside an aggregate?

Comment: Hi Gordan, yes that is the tricky part I wish to obtain the counts of the categories find the ones with the lowests values and display model,VIN,cost based on the minimum category values

Comment: another question how can i format the cost column as $XXXX.XX?

Comment: @ITworldR By the way, a I said yesterday, you just need to set the display properties. However, your accepted answer is unnecessary complication and creates more overhead.

Comment: @Andomar . . . This is an aggregation function instead a window function, and yes, it is allowed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I guess I always tried with the parenthesis wrong (like `min(count(*) over ())`)

Answer (score 1):

```
with    cnt_stock as
        (
        select  count(*) over (partition by category) cat_cnt
        ,       model
        ,       category
        from    stock
        )
select  *
from    cnt_stock
where   cat_cnt = 
        (
        select  min(cat_cnt)
        from    cnt_stock
        )
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ffe12/6/0)

Comment: `select  top 1 count(*)` in Oracle? Not an Oracle feature.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Ah it's Oracle.  Is it even possible to limit subqueries in Oracle?  I've updated the answer to work around that.

Comment: The **top-n row limiting** feature is available from `12c`. Else, `rownum` with `order by` in `sub-query`. Or, `analytic function` would anyway work.